# Sitemaps - do I need to submit each sitemap in sitemap_index.xml to Google Webmaster tools?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, sitemap

I am having a Wordpress blog on my CentOS server. There is no sitemap.xml in the root directory but there is `sitemap_index.xml` file in the root directory which contains the following code:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/xml-sitemap-xsl.php"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>
            http://mywebsite.com/post-sitemap.xml
        </loc>
        <lastmod>
            2012-12-18T19:47:47+00:00
        </lastmod>
    </sitemap>

    <sitemap>
        <loc>
            http://mywebsite.com/page-sitemap.xml
        </loc>
        <lastmod>
            2012-12-18T17:32:49+00:00
        </lastmod>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

**My question:** Which sitemap should I submit to [Google Webmasters Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)? Options are:

1. Only `sitemap_index.xml`
2. Only `post-sitemap.xml` and `page-sitemap.xml`
3. All 3 (sitemap_index.xml, post-sitemap.xml and page-sitemap.xml)
4. Any other, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just submit the master sitemap. It's purpose is to tell them about the other sitemaps so there is no need to submit them.

Comment: Thanks John. By master sitemap you mean 'sitemap_index.xml'?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I meant. :)

Answer (score 3):

According to Google Webmaster Tools support article http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71453

> When you've created your Sitemap index file, save it and submit it to
>   Google. As long as you've uploaded and saved all your Sitemaps, you
>   don't need to submit each Sitemap individually. Just submit the
>   Sitemap index file and you're good to go. You can submit up to 500
>   Sitemap index files for each site in your account.

Sample code on their page